# BitArray CopyTo not long enough

Tags: vb.net

I have a converter class I borrowed that converts BitArray to an Integer so I can store it in the registry. The BitArray is 32 single bits, so New BitArray(32).

The problem is that I am getting an error  Destination array was not long enough on the CopyTo.

Is there a way around this?

```
Public Shared Function ToNumeral(binary As BitArray) As Integer
    If binary Is Nothing Then
        Throw New ArgumentNullException("Binary conversion error: Field is empty")
    End If

    Dim result = New Integer(0) {}
    binary.CopyTo(result, 0)
    Return result(0)
End Function
```

Comment: If you check `binary.Count`, what value do you get?

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can reproduce the problem.  I can't reproduce the error with your code.

Comment: The only example I can give is that in the main module,  Public PrintOpts As New BitArray(33, True) is declared. The conversion is to take place after a form with a CheckedListBox control is selected, then button pressed. Code for button press:

Dim RegKey = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\MyApp\Options"
        For i = 1 To 32
            Main.PrintOpts(i) = CheckedListBox1.GetItemCheckState(i - 1)
        Next

        My.Computer.Registry.SetValue(RegKey, "PrintOpts", BinaryConverter.ToNumeral(Main.PrintOpts))
        Close()

Comment: If you really did initialize your bit array with `New BitArray(32)`, then the count would not be 33.  Something is wrong ***before*** calling your `ToNumeral` function.  Can't help you with that because we can't see it.

Comment: It's 33, I misspoke.

Comment: Are you saying that you are doing `New BitArray(33)`?

Comment: Yes - Public PrintOpts As New BitArray(33, True)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Integer` data type can only hold 32 bits.  If you declare your `BitArray` to be of size `33` (as you clarified in the comments), then that is too large for an `Integer`.

You need to revise what you are trying to accomplish.  But to get a single `Integer` back from your `ToNumeral` function, you can't go past 32 bits of information.

Comment: It's hard to suggest any alternatives, because I don't know what you are trying to do, where your bits are coming from, why you need an integer, etc. I don't know your requirements.